# Reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am just a little confused between two statements.

1.

```
    int a = 42;
    int *p = &a; //declares pointer p to a
    int &r = *p; //this is not the way to declare a reference to a pointer, but what does this statement do
```

To print value of, it can be done by

```
    cout << a << *p << r;
```

All the above will print the value of a, but how, that is what i want to know.

2. Now this is how a reference to a pointer is defined

   ```
   int i = 42;
   int *p;
   int *&r = p; //declares reference r to pointer p
   r = &i; //stores the address of i in pointer p
   ```

I just want to understand why the first one doesn't define a reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

In this code snippet

```
int a = 42;
int *p = &a; //declares pointer p to a
int &r = *p; //this is not the way to declare a reference to a pointer, but what does this
```

the expression `*p` yields lvalue of the object `a` because the pointer `p` points to the object. So this declaration

```
int &r = *p;
```

declares a reference to the same object `a` using an indirect access to the object through the pointer `p`.

From the C++ Standard (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 1 The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which
>   it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”. [ Note: Indirection
>   through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid.
>   **The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example)**; this lvalue must not be converted to a
>   prvalue, see 4.1. —end note ]

The difference between the two code snippets presented in the question is that in the first code snippet there is declared a reference to an object of type `int` (int a = 42; ) using indirection by means of a pointer. While in the second code snippet there is declared a reference to a pointer (int *p;).

Answer (score 4):

lets break it down (from Right to Left):

```
int &r = *p;
```

this

```
*p
```

de -references the pointer

and this

```
int& r
```

is the reference declaration

at the end

```
int& r = *p;
```

is equivalent to

```
int& r = a;
```

---

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    int *p = &a; //declares pointer p to a
    int &r = *p;

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "r: " << r << endl;

    cout << "changing a:" << endl;
    a = 17;
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "r: " << r << endl;
    cout << "changing r:" << endl;

    r = 0;
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "r: " << r << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the first case you've just declared a regular reference to int and you assigned ***p** to it, which is an int. ***p** is not a pointer, but the value that the pointer p points to - in this case it's just the value of **a**.